# Adding extension to URL: Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, hyperlink

I'm setting up some link_to xml views within a rails app. How can the url display the .xml extension?

```
Need it to appear as:
http://localhost:3000/test/1-testing.xml

Currently it appears as:
http://localhost:3000/test/1-testing
```

Answer (score 16):

In Rails 3, assuming your path is `foo_path`, then you want:

```
foo_path(:format=>:xml)
```

In a `link_to`, you can do

```
link_to "link text", foo_path(:format => :xml)
```

And with more options:

```
link_to "link text", foo_path(:format => :xml), :id=>"foo_id", :class=>"foo_class"
```

(This question is old as heck, but I thought I'd answer to help out anyone who finds this via Google, like I did.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to link to the instance @test, try:

```
test_url(@test, :format => :xml)
```

Comment: This is my link code: 
<%= link_to 'Map', {:action => 'map', :id => entry, :format => :xml} %>

And it displays as:
http://localhost:3000/entries/map/1-sample-form?format=xml

And it needs to be:
http://localhost:3000/entries/map/1-sample-form.xml